# Cannot get TEdit handle from TPanel

Tags: c#, delphi, winapi, handle

I have a main window that has a TEdit and a TButton that I need the handles to. They are both inside a TPanel. My code so far is

```
    public void SendPacket(string packet)
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = Window.FindWindow(null, "AlissaAnalyzer");
        IntPtr panel = Window.FindWindowEx(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "TPanel", "");
        IntPtr edithWnd = Window.FindWindowEx(panel, IntPtr.Zero, "TEdit", "");
        IntPtr buttonhWnd = Window.FindWindowEx(panel, IntPtr.Zero, "TButton", "");
        //Do stuff with handles
    }
```

This gives me the handles for the TPanel and the TButton, but 0 for the TEdit. I have no idea why this doesn't work since it follows the structure that Spy++ gives me:

[image: Spy++ Structure of Window]

Is there something I'm missing here? Do I need a different method to get the handle for TEdit? Am I using FindWindowEx wrong?

Comment: If you're looking to do UI automation from .NET the White project may simplify your efforts: http://white.codeplex.com/

Comment: I don't think that TEdit's parent window is the panel... try IntPtr edithWnd = Window.FindWindowEx(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "TEdit", "");

Comment: P.S. I've also noticed that you have a TMemo but not TEdit in the screenshot, could it be that the memo is used in stead of a TEdit field?

Comment: @Dorin The edits parent is the TPanel, shown by the picture above. The TMemo is a completely different object on the window. And I am certain the TEdit is what I'm looking for since I used Spy++'s find control tool to get it.

Comment: @ozdrgnaDiies my bad, seems that I see double... please ignore my previous comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spy++ shows that the edit box has no text in it. Strange, even the tButton has no caption. Finding the tEdit should work the first time but based on your other question but as soon as you send some text to the edit the FindWindowEx call will fail since you're always passing "" as the text.  You can pass null instead to find any match.

Comment: You've helped me yet again. Sending null instead of "" got me the handle instantly. Thank you very much.